Python 3: TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class BaseConnection with abstract method create_connection
I am upgrading some very old Python code from Python 2 to Python 3. There is a simple method to check rabbitmq connection using Pika.
    from contextlib import closing
    from pika import URLParameters, BaseConnection

    def check_rabbitmq(self):
        conn_params = URLParameters(self.config.rabbitmq_params['amqp.url'])
        with closing(BaseConnection(conn_params)):
            return True

However, in Python 3 it returns
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class BaseConnection with abstract method create_connection I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

BaseConnection is just a abstract base class and can't be used as is. You need to use one of the connection classes inherited from the base class, like BlockingConnection

As per the error, Can't instantiate abstract class BaseConnection with abstract method create_connection. For that what we can do is to use one of its concrete subclasses for establishing a connection, such as BlockingConnection. using that below is the modified chunk of code:
def check_rabbitmq(self):
    conn_params = pika.URLParameters(self.config.rabbitmq_params['amqp.url'])
    with pika.BlockingConnection(conn_params) as connection:
        return True

Make sure you also import pika at the top.

BaseConnection is an abstract class, meaning it is not meant to be instantiated directly, but rather subclassed, ie:
class MyRabbitConnection(BaseConnection):
    def create_connection(self, *args):
        # your code here

However, you shouldn't be dealing with implementing this yourself, you should use some of the existing connecting methods. You can find various examples here.

Thank you - what would the best connection method be for a quick "connection check" as part of a healthcheck? Would it be SelectConnection?

I would use BlockingConnection, as explained here: https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.13.1/examples/blocking_basic_get.html. I'd just surround it with try/except, and if you don't get exception, you have connectivity.
